# biblatex - Order last-first for the names of multiple editors?

Tags: biblatex

For all bibliography items containing multiple editors, I must print the same order of names for multiple editors as I have them for multiple authors. For the authors, I got it to work (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles/13076#13076)), but this does not cover the case of multiple editors (unless I made a mistake?).

The relevant part of a representative bibliography item currently looks like

> G. E. R. Lloyd/G. E. L. Owen (ed. by)

but it must be

> Lloyd, G. E. R./Owen, G. E. L. (ed. by)

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear,
backend=bibtex,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
citereset=chapter,
maxcitenames=3,
dashed=false,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
terseinits=false
maxbibnames=99,
uniquename=init
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}{\printtext}{\printtext[parens]}{}{}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
@InCollection{brandt,
  options     = {useprefix=false},
  hyphenation     = {german},
  indexsorttitle  = {Nordischen Lander von der Mitte des 11. Jahrhunderts bis 1448},
  author      = {von Brandt, Ahasver and Erich Hoffmann},
  editor      = {Ferdinand Seibt},
  indextitle      = {Nordischen L{\"a}nder von der Mitte des 11.~Jahrhunderts bis 1448, Die},
  title       = {Die nordischen L{\"a}nder von der Mitte des 11.~Jahrhunderts bis 1448},
  shorttitle      = {Die nordischen L{\"a}nder},
  booktitle   = {Europa im Hoch- und Sp{\"a}tmittelalter},
  series      = {Handbuch der europ{\"a}ischen Geschichte},
  number      = {2},
  publisher   = {Klett-Cotta},
  location    = {Stuttgart},
  date        = {1987},
  pages       = {884--917},
  annotation      = {An \texttt{incollection} entry with a \texttt{series} and a \texttt{number}.
            Note the format of the printed name and compare the \texttt{useprefix} option in
            the \texttt{options} field as well as \texttt{vangennep}. Also note the
            \texttt{indextitle, and \texttt{indexsorttitle} fields}}
}
@InProceedings{moraux,
  keywords    = {secondary},
  hyphenation     = {french},
  indexsorttitle  = {De Anima dans la tradition grecque},
  author      = {Moraux, Paul},
  editor      = {Lloyd, G. E. R. and Owen, G. E. L.},
  indextitle      = {\emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque, Le},
  title       = {Le \emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque},
  subtitle    = {Quelques aspects de l'interpretation du trait{\'e}, de Theophraste {\`a}
            Themistius},
  shorttitle      = {\emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque},
  booktitle   = {Aristotle on Mind and the Senses},
  booktitleaddon  = {Proceedings of the Seventh Symposium Aristotelicum},
  eventdate   = {1975},
  publisher   = cup,
  location    = {Cambridge},
  date        = {1979},
  pages       = {281--324},
  annotation      = {This is a typical \texttt{inproceedings} entry. Note the \texttt{booksubtitle},
            \texttt{shorttitle}, \texttt{indextitle}, and \texttt{indexsorttitle} fields.
            Also note the \texttt{eventdate} field.}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}



\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
    \item For the case of multiple editors, these are just some words.\footcite[Cp.][p. xi]{moraux}. This currently looks like
    \begin{verbatim}
    G. E. R. Lloyd/G. E. L. Owen (ed. by)
    \end{verbatim}
    but I must have
    \begin{verbatim}
    Lloyd, G. E. R./Owen, G. E. L. (ed. by)
    \end{verbatim}
\end{itemize}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The format of names is specified by the command `\DeclareNameFormat` and `\DeclareNameAlias`. The default definitions are done inside `biblatex.def`.

The relevant part of the file is:

**`biblatex.def`**

```
% Used in the bibliography

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first/first-last}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{bookauthor}{author}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{editora}{editor}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorb}{editor}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorc}{editor}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{default}

\DeclareNameAlias{byauthor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{bybookauthor}{byauthor}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditora}{byeditor}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditorb}{byeditor}
\DeclareNameAlias{byeditorc}{byeditor}
\DeclareNameAlias{bytranslator}{default}

\DeclareNameAlias{withcommentator}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{withannotator}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{withintroduction}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{withforeword}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{withafterword}{default}
```

As you can see most of the name formats are done by the default name format which has the following meaning: `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{first-last}`.

Using the style `authoryear` means that the following redefinition occurs:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}
```

So to change every thing to `last-first` you only need:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
```

[image]