# Biblatex with biber splits long name to first and last name

Tags: biblatex, zotero

I'm writing my thesis and I'm stucked with a problem with BibLaTeX. The sorting of the bibliography entries is functional. BUT the author-field is separated automatically to first- and surname, although there is no extra separation in my `.bib` file. You can see it, when you are activate the `firstinit` option of the BibLaTeX package or in the picture below.

[image]

I found an answer, where I have to put an extra pair of `{}` braces around the authors name. But that's not a practical solution because my `.bib` file is generated and updated by Zotero. Given extra `{}` braces to the name in Zotero are causing an error while compiling.

I would appreciate your help! Combining different `bibstyle` and `citeystyle`, like it's mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427292/combining-numeric-citation-with-non-numeric-style-in-biblatex), doesn't solve the problem.

Here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citestyle=numeric,
    sorting=anyvt,  
    labelnumber=true,
    %firstinits=true,
    block=nbpar,            
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
% % % % Beispiele Literatur
\begin{filecontents}{sources.bib}
@online{hessischeverwaltungBegriffeETRS,
    title = {Begriffe - ETRS},
    url = {http://sapos.hvbg.hessen.de/term.php#ETRS89},
    urldate = {2019-03-02},
    author = {Hessische Verwaltung für Bodenmanagement und Geoinformation}
}

@online{lglnOpenDataPortale,
    title = {Open Data Portale | Geodatenportal Niedersachsen},
    url = {http://www.geodaten.niedersachsen.de/startseite/gdini/open_data_portale/open-data-136000.html},
    urldate = {2019-02-23},
    author = {Landesamt für Geoinformation und Landesvermessung Niedersachsen (LGLN)}
}

@online{openknowledgefoundationOpenDatabaseLicense2009,
    title = {Open Database License (ODbL) v1.0},
    url = {https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/},
    urldate = {2019-03-05},
    date = {2009-06-25},
    author = {Open Knowledge Foundation}
}
\end{filecontents}


\bibliography{sources.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\autocite{lglnOpenDataPortale,hessischeverwaltungBegriffeETRS,openknowledgefoundationOpenDatabaseLicense2009}.


\printbibliography
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

This is the result – wrong order depending on the first letter.

[image]

This would be the right order, I managed this with that extra pair of `{}` braces.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For corporate authors, you need to protect it with an extra pair of braces, like `author = {{Hessische Verwaltung für Bodenmanagement und Geoinformation}},`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I also found in other posts, but as I mentioned, that's not an option for my auto generated and updated bib-file with Zotero. Adding the extra braces in Zotero causing an error.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to tell Zotero to do that, as I don't use it. But that is what is required from the side of biblatex. (And of BibTeX, for that matter).

Comment: okay, maybe you're right and the problem should be solved in the export, that's a new idea I didn't thought about before, found [this](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/issues/565) - something with "non-dropping particles", try it tomorrow.

but if anybody has a solution, you can also try so share it ;)

Comment: Are you entering the author in single field mode in Zotero? There should only be one field visible when entering a corporate author, not two fields for given and family name.

Comment: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/3275/entering-corporate-authors, https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/19721/bibtex-export-for-corporate-authors-single-name-only for the `.bib` side the standard reference is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864. I can get the braces to work automatically if I switch the author field to 'single field mode' and just input the name there. See also https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/item_types_and_fields under 'author' and https://www.zotero.org/support/getting_stuff_into_your_library under 'names'.

Comment: So, I tried the hint from your answer first, David. It solved the problem immediately. 
To be honest I haven't recognized this little toggle button for years!

So thank's a lot to all of you and for your helpful advices!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you found out and [gusbrs commented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477949/biblatex-with-biber-splits-long-name-to-first-and-last-name/478140#comment1207050_477949), BibTeX and Biber expect corporate authors (or rather corporate authors whose name consists of more than one word) to be wrapped in an extra pair of curly braces. See also [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864).

So you need the author "Hessische Verwaltung für Bodenmanagement und Geoinformation" to be exported as

```
author = {{Hessische Verwaltung für Bodenmanagement und Geoinformation}},
```

to avoid Biber or BibTeX trying to parse the name into family and given name parts and making undesirable sorting or `giveninits` decisions based on that.

---

Zotero should do that for you automatically as long as you input the name in a way that Zotero understands. Its name fields have two modes: *one-field* mode and *two-field* mode. See also https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/item_types_and_fields (search for 'author') and https://www.zotero.org/support/getting_stuff_into_your_library (search for 'names'). In two-field mode Zotero splits the name into family/last and given/first name name parts that are entered separately in two subfields. One-field mode allows you to enter the full name as one unit directly. People's names should normally be given in two-field mode, corporate authors in one-field mode.

In two field-mode the name is split into two components: family/last name and given/first name. The parts are separated by a comma and are input separately.

[image: Two-field mode: (last) and (first) in two different fields, they are separated by a comma]

You can click on the little field symbol next to the plus and minus to switch to the other field mode

[image: field switcher highlighted]

In one-field mode the input consist of only one field.

[image: One-field mode: (full name) in one field]

Corporate authors should be entered in one-field/full-name mode without additional braces (see also [David Purton's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477949/biblatex-with-biber-splits-long-name-to-first-and-last-name/478140#comment1207077_477949)). The exporter automatically adds the necessary braces to ensure that the full name is not split into parts.

[image: "Hessische Verwaltung für Bodenmanagement und Geoinformation" entered in one-field mode]

The entry will then be exported correctly. In this example the `.bib` file has

```
author = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf
          and {Hessische Verwaltung für Bodenmanagement und Geoinformation}},
```

as expected.

The switch button next to the name can serve as a handy indicator to tell you in which input mode you are. Just remember that the icon switches to the other mode, so if you see the two-field icon you are in one-field mode and vice versa.

This is also discussed in many threads at the Zotero support forum, for example https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/3275/entering-corporate-authors and https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/19721/bibtex-export-for-corporate-authors-single-name-only